# ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE syntax and EXCLUDED error on cursor.executemany

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a simplified postgres (ver 13) table below with updated rows generated in python with psycopg2.
My question is when I update the price field in the rows, I can't complete the update because of the following errors of ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE. If I don't use ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE , I can update the chart but I would like ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE because it eliminates duplicate rows.

With ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE , I only need to update the fields "price" and "last_updated" but update only when the rows match the "id,item,original_price_date"

The following errors I get ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE :

Error : syntax error at or near "="

```
# update the prices within the existing data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['5/3/2010', 'rock', 15],
                            ['4/15/2010', 'paper', 11],
                            ['2/3/2015', 'scissor', 13]]),
                             columns = ['original_price_date', 'item', 'price'])
tuples_for_dB = [tuple(x) for x in df.to_numpy()]
sql_script = '''INSERT INTO ''' + TABLE_ + ''' (
  original_price_date, item, price, created_date, last_updated) 
  VALUES (%s, %s, %s, transaction_timestamp(), transaction_timestamp())
  ON CONFLICT (id, item, original_price_date)
  DO UPDATE SET (price, last_updated = EXCLUDED.price, EXCLUDED.transaction_timestamp());'''
```

Error : relation "price_data" does not exist

```
sql_script = '''INSERT INTO ''' + TABLE_ + ''' (
  original_price_date, item, price, created_date, last_updated) 
  VALUES (%s, %s, %s, transaction_timestamp(), transaction_timestamp())
  ON CONFLICT (id, item, original_price_date)
  DO UPDATE SET (price, last_updated) = (EXCLUDED.price, EXCLUDED.transaction_timestamp());'''
```

My original creation of the data :

```
   # postGRESQL connection details
DATABASE_INITIAL_ = 'postgres'
DATABASE_ = 'data'
TABLE_ = 'price_data'
USER_ = 'postgres'
SERVERNAME_ = 'localhost'
PASSWORD_ = password_
HOST_ = '127.0.0.1'
PORT_ = '5432'

#establishing the connection
conn = psycopg2.connect(database = DATABASE_,
                        user = USER_,
                        password = PASSWORD_,
                        host = HOST_,
                        port = PORT_);
conn.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT);
conn.autocommit = True

# Creating a cursor object using the cursor() method
cursor = conn.cursor()

sql = "SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE datname = " + "'" + DATABASE_ + "'"
cursor.execute(sql)

# If dB does not exist create the dB
exists = cursor.fetchone()
print(exists)
if not exists:
    print('does not exist')
    #Preparing query to create a database
    sql = '''CREATE database '''+DATABASE_;

    #Creating a database
    cursor.execute(sql)

# Creating the table
sql = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ''' + TABLE_ + ''' (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  original_price_date DATE NOT NULL,
  item TEXT NOT NULL,
  price NUMERIC NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  created_date TIMESTAMPTZ NULL DEFAULT TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP(),
  last_updated TIMESTAMPTZ NULL DEFAULT TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP());'''
cursor.execute(sql)

# update the table with data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['5/3/2010', 'rock', 0.9],
                            ['4/15/2010', 'paper', 6.5],
                            ['2/3/2015', 'scissor', 3.9],
                            ['3/23/2017', 'ball', 1.1],
                            ['4/7/2013', 'tire', 5.4]]),
                             columns = ['original_price_date', 'item', 'price'])
tuples_for_dB = [tuple(x) for x in df.to_numpy()]
sql_script = '''INSERT INTO ''' + TABLE_ + ''' (
  original_price_date, item, price, created_date, last_updated) 
  VALUES (%s, %s, %s, transaction_timestamp(), transaction_timestamp());'''

try:
    cursor.executemany(sql_script, tuples_for_dB);                
    success = True
except psycopg2.Error as e:
    error = e.pgcode
    print(f'Error : {e.args[0]}')
    success = False
if success:
    print(f'\nData inserted successfully........')      
    print(f'Table INSERT sql commit comment :\n"{sql_script}"\n')
elif success == False:
    print(f'\nData NOT inserted successfully XXXXXX')      
            
# Preparing query to drop a table
sql = '''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ''' + TABLE_ + ";"
# Creating the table
cursor.execute(sql)

conn.close()
```

Comment: The problem in the first snipped is the parentheses.  It needs to be `(field,field,field) = (value,value,value)`.  You fixed that in the second snippet.  As for the `price_data does not exist error`, in the file where that happened, did you connect to the correct database?

Comment: I don't see you calling `conn.commt()` anywhere in the creation script.  If you open the database in the `psql` command line tool, do you see the table?

Comment: Yes. I see the table with the cmd line so it is indeed in the database. Upon running my script at the end is a DROP TABLE cmd. If I comment this out the table with the initial data persists in postgres. Sorry I added it because I had to re-create the table over and over again. Per the commit question, I added conn.autocommit = True.

Comment: OK, but the failing code you showed us is not from the creation script, right?  If you were dropping the table at the end of the creation script, then it's not going to exist when you do your dataframe stuff.  Right?

Comment: This table is very simplified for this question. The ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE error was caused by my million row database. The same error applies here. I am still getting a syntax error  Error : syntax error at or near "=". I can edit my original post to take the DROP TABLE out.

Comment: Did you see my first comment?  You do have the wrong syntax.  It has to be like an INSERT statement:  `DO UPDATE SET (field,field,field) = (value,value,value)`.

Comment: Yes. Another error fixing the code UPDATE SET (field,field,field) = (value,value,value) Error : there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification.

Comment: DO UPDATE SET (price, last_updated) = (EXCLUDED.price, EXCLUDED.transaction_timestamp());'''      Error : schema "excluded" does not exist
LINE 5: ...DATE SET (price, last_updated) = (EXCLUDED.price, EXCLUDED.t...

Comment: Maybe postgres isn't recognizing that upon matching the id+item+original_price_date all need to be the same

Comment: And it is an insert statement : sql_script = '''INSERT INTO ''' + TABLE_ + ''' (
  original_price_date, item, price, created_date, last_updated) 
  VALUES (%s, %s, %s, transaction_timestamp(), transaction_timestamp())
  ON CONFLICT (id, item, original_price_date)
  DO UPDATE SET (price, last_updated) = (EXCLUDED.price, EXCLUDED.transaction_timestamp());'''

Comment: The error is clear: that table does not exist. Besides, `EXCLUDED.transaction_timestamp()` should lose the `EXCLUDED.`.

Comment: The table does exist. Here is the table selected : data=# SELECT * FROM price_data;
 id | original_price_date |  item   | price |         created_date          |         last_updated
----+---------------------+---------+-------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------
  1 | 2010-05-03          | rock    |   0.9 | 2021-03-19 01:03:10.415393-03 | 2021-03-19 01:03:10.415393-03
  2 | 2010-04-15          | paper   |   6.5 | 2021-03-19 01:03:10.416503-03 | 2021-03-19 01:03:10.416503-03
  3 | 2015-02-03          | scissor |   3.9 |...............

Comment: I agree I should delete the EXCLUDED from the last_updated field.   DO UPDATE SET (price, last_updated) = (EXCLUDED.price, transaction_timestamp());''' But I get the following error. Error : there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a constraint row (CONSTRAINT com UNIQUE (original_price_date,item))) where I created the table.

```
sql = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ''' + TABLE_ + ''' (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  original_price_date DATE NOT NULL,
  item TEXT NOT NULL,
  price NUMERIC NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  created_date TIMESTAMPTZ NULL DEFAULT TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP(),
  last_updated TIMESTAMPTZ NULL DEFAULT TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP(),
  CONSTRAINT com UNIQUE (original_price_date,item));'''
```

Then I could insert the data NOT creating duplicate rows of (original_price_date,item) by the following statement.

```
 sql = '''INSERT INTO ''' + TABLE_ + '''(original_price_date, item, price) 
                VALUES (%s, %s, %s)
                ON CONFLICT (original_price_date, item) 
                DO UPDATE 
                    SET (price, last_updated)  = (EXCLUDED.price,TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP());'''
```